# Understanding permutations with backtracking

Tags: python, permutation, backtracking

I'm trying to figure out how the following backtracking solution works to generate all the permutations of integers given as a list:

```
def permutations(arr):
    res = []
    backtrack(arr, [], set(), res)
    print(res)

def backtrack(arr, temp, visited, res):
    if len(temp) == len(arr):
        res.append(temp[:])
    else:
        for num in arr:
            if num in visited: continue
            visited.add(num)
            temp.append(num)
            backtrack(arr, temp, visited, res)
            visited.remove(num)
            temp.pop()
```

Executing with the following:

```
permutations([1, 2, 3])
```

The result is as expected:

> [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]

What i don't understand is the `temp.pop()` call at the end of the loop.
I know that `pop()` discards the last element of the list, but why is it necessary here?

I'd really appreciate if someone could explain this to me.

Comment: Because there can be only one n'th element in that list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary because on the next iteration the function will `append` again an element, so if you didn't `pop` beforehand the list would keep growing in size. Since `backtrack` adds results only if the length of `temp` equals the length of the original `arr` it won't add anything beyond the first permutation `[1, 2, 3]` (because from there on, the `temp` list keeps growing).

We can just remove that line (`temp.pop()`) and see what the results look like:

```
[[1, 2, 3]]
```

Now if we also change that results are added whenever `len(temp) >= len(arr)` then we'll see how `temp` grows in size:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3]]
```

We get fewer results here because for each recursive call beyond `[1, 2, 3]` the `temp` list is immediately copied without ever reaching the `for` loop.